# Change a source code of a Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I need to add a logger to a Spring Boot class, anotherwords edit the Spring sources. It's a Maven project developed in STS. Is this even possible?

Comment: Fork it, add your log statement, compile it locally, and pull in that version as your dependency.

Comment: Branch the code and change it.  Of course, you're now stuck with that version.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I need to see a callbackUrl parameter send  to a Twitter API during sign-in request (org.springframework.social.security.provider.OAuth1AuthenticationService) from spring-social-security

Comment: Did you try debugging ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this even possible?

Yes, it is very much possible. Spring is an opensource project. Go to their github repository, clone the release that you want. (If you are feeling adventurous, and would like to live on the edge always, go for the latest code in their master branch). Build it and export the jar to your internal repo (Nexus/JFrog Artifactory etc) and refer it from there.

Downside of this is, now you are stuck with that version of Spring. To further maintain your version of spring (pulling and merging the bug fixes and new features happening in the upstream), you need to fork the spring repo to the internal git and build it from there.

If you think, that logging statement is relevant for others too (outside the scope of your organization), in the spring github repo, feel free to open an issue or create a PR. If it gets merged, you can claim that you are a Spring committer!! :)